# Only display 'All fields must be completed' error once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a page out of javascript. I'm pretty new to all this, so bear with me.

I have a form, and when you press submit I have the following bit to see if the fields are left blank:

```
function calculatePrice() 
{

var GasPrice = document.getElementById("number1").value;
var Distance = document.getElementById("number2").value;
var Mileage = document.getElementById("number3").value;
var norepeat = false;

if (norepeat==false && (GasPrice =="" || Distance =="" || Mileage =="")) 
{
var para=document.createElement("p"); 
para.setAttribute("class", "error");
var node=document.createTextNode("All fields must be completed");
para.appendChild(node);
var element=document.getElementById("content");
element.appendChild(para);
var norepeat = true;
}
```

I created the error as a paragraph tag that appears. The problem is that when I press submit more than once, it writes the error message every time. I tried the norepeat variable thing, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help?

Comment: You're resetting norepeat every function call.  It may work as you intended if you move the variable declaration outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not completely sure your intentions, it'd have to look something more like:

```
var norepeat = false;

function calculatePrice() {
    if(!norepeat && (/* other conditions here */)) {
        norepeat = true;
    }

    return !(/* other conditions above */);
}
```

Where `norepeat` is defined in a global scope. Also, remember to use `===` as opposed to `==`. And trimming the string before testing it wouldn't be a horrible idea...

But, wouldn't you want the errors to still persist if the user hasn't corrected them - isn't that the point of validation?

Comment: The way he's doing it, the error probably won't disappear til the form is submitted, leaving the page.

Comment: @eshellborn I'm not sure if you realize, but the `var` keyword declares a variable.  You don't write `var` again when reassigning its value.

Comment: @numbers1311407 were you answering my last question there, or hinting that I should include a `return false;`?

Comment: answering :-)  The calculatePrice function is inserting HTML.  If he's worried about keeping it from firing twice, presumably there's likely no code that removes the error.

Comment: @numbers1311407 Then something should presumably be returning `!(GasPrice === "" || Distance === "" || Mileage === "");`, no?

Comment: Perhaps, but then he'd probably have reported that the form was submitting with errors.  He's probably not attaching this to onsubmit or anything, just calling it.

Comment: The post was "I have a form and when you press submit" so I think the return value is warranted :)

Comment: Yeah I know about the only declaring a variable once, I just messed up. Thanks for the help. @numbers1311407

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this. This assumes you add a new div "myError" that holds your error message. You'll also need to consider not submitting the form too if validation doesn't pass.

```
function calculatePrice() {

        var GasPrice = document.getElementById("number1").value;
        var Distance = document.getElementById("number2").value;
        var Mileage = document.getElementById("number3").value;
        var error = document.getElementById("myError");

        if (GasPrice == "" || Distance == "" || Mileage == "") {
            error.style.display = "block";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            error.style.display = "none";
            return true;
        }
    }
```